# sed Unrecognized command

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

I am trying to match the pattern and print above few lines, using sed i can able to do that but in script i am not able to pass that. i am getting the below it takes arguments as commands how to avoid that.

This is my simple for loop script

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in `cat test.txt`
do
echo "***************************************************************************"
echo '\n'
echo $i
sed -n "'1,/$i/p'  debug.log | tail -14"
echo '\n'
echo "***************************************************************************"
done
```

> sed -n "'1,/Ref555330/p'  debug.log | tail -14"
>
> ```
> Unrecognized command: '1,/Ref555330/p'  debug.log | tail -14
> ```

Kindly guide me to solve this thread.

Comment: What is `sed -n "'1,/$i/p'  debug.log | tail -14"` supposed to do?

Comment: it will print the above 13 lines from the matched pattern.

Comment: You are feeding sed "'1,/$i/p'  debug.log | tail -14" as a command. Remove all quotes and surround the sed command by double quotes i.e. "1,/$i/p"

Answer (score 3):

Give double quotes only for sed command

```
sed -n "1,/$i/p"  debug.log | tail -14
```

Comment: Thanks its working but ,Whats wrong with the sed sometimes its printing 13 wrong lines even the pattern not matched :-(

Comment: When the pattern is not matched, `sed` tends to treat `1,/pattern/` as `1,$` - i.e. it just prints the entire file, which renders the range specification moot... This is because the way `sed` works is to start at line 1, and until it finds a matching line, it performs the requested action on each line. It doesn't actually try to find the range first.

Answer (score 0):

sed is just not the right tool for anything involving more than 1 line and any time you write a loop in shell just to manipulate text you have the wrong approach. It looks like you have a file named test.txt of regular expressions and you want to get the 14 lines above each RE from some other file debug.log. That's just one simple awk command, something like this (untested since you didn't provide any sample input or expected output):

```
awk '
NR==FNR { res[$0]; next }
{
    line[FNR] = $0
    for (re in res)
        if ($0 ~ re)
            hit[FNR]
    next
}
END {
    for (i=1; i<=FNR; i++) {
        if (i in hit) {
            print "***************************************************************************"
            for (j=i-14; j<=i; j++)
                print line[j]
            print "***************************************************************************"
        }
    }
}
' test.txt debug.log
```

Comment: it saying syntax error.
awk: syntax error near line 6
awk: illegal statement near line 6
awk: syntax error near line 12
awk: illegal statement near line 12
awk: syntax error near line 20

Comment: its a solaris machine

Comment: Whenever you get that error message it means you are using old, broken awk (/usr/bin/awk on Solaris). Never use that awk because it is, well, old and broken. On Solaris use /usr/xpg4/bin/awk or nawk.

Comment: Thanks alot its working like charm, but when i process multiples at the time it saying limit exceeded error? is there any possibilities to avoid that.?

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific about what you mean by "multiples" (multiples of what?) and copy/paste the error message.

Comment: Sorry typho :
Multiples of files.
/usr/xpg4/bin/awk: line 8 (NR=1047): Record too long (LIMIT: 19999 bytes)

Comment: Update your question to show what you are doing and provide some info on the content of the files (e.g. N lines of M chars each). Also, try nawk instead.